# How to change End date on selected event of start date in drupal 7?

Tags: jquery, date, drupal-7

I am using date module and i wants to change End date on selected event of start date.

i have checked below code but it is not working.

```
 $('#edit-line-item-fields-field-event-date-und-0-value-datepicker-popup-0').change(function () {
        var dt = this.val();
  $('#edit-line-item-fields-field-event-date-und-0-value2-datepicker-popup-0').val(dt);

    //OR  
$("#edit-line-item-fields-field-event-date-und-0-value2-datepicker-popup-0").datepicker({ minDate: +1 });   
 });
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console? Please provide details of what is not happening or errors occurring. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. In first case i am getting " TypeError: this.val is not a function " error

Comment: in 2nd case console does not show any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding out what `this` refers to (perhaps by using `console.log(this)`). My guess is that this is a plain HTML element, which will not have the `val()` method.

If so, use `$(this).val()` instead.